# iOS storyboard: few buttons and one segue

Tags: ios, storyboard

In my app first screen content few button (it is password screen) and user must press few buttons and go to next screen.
How I can create one segue for all button with same behavior?
Or, I must create one IBAction and programmaticaly call push method?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Or just call `performSegueWithIdentifier:` from that `IBAction`

Comment: Thank you! But, I must check password in IBAction method, or in prepareForSegue: method?

Comment: Do the password check in the IBAction if you automatically wants to go forward when the correct password has been entered.